# Create additional Target Parameter in deployed Application

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment

I use Visual Studio 2019 to create an application and I deploy it using ClickOnce deployment. While installing, the app creates shortcuts on the user's PC:

1. In the Start Menu
2. On the Desktop

In the properties of the desktop shortcut (under Shortcut -> Target), it says (Path and file modified for this question):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AssenblyInfomationCompany\suiteName\AsenblyInfo.exe"
```

Question: how can I achieve that when publishing the App (in VS) a command line parameter is added (both: in the desktop shortcut and the start menu shortcut) like /opt1?

e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AssenblyInfomationCompany\suiteName\AsenblyInfo.exe /opt1"
```